# Channel owner permissions on YouTube reports API

Tags: youtube-api

I seem to be unable to get video reports data from a YouTube channel that I am not the Primary Owner of, even if I am authorized as a manager or an owner.  Using a token of the actual primary channel owner, no problems.  Using the token from a manager or owner I get a 403 forbidden.  Anyone have experience on this?  Do I need the content owner ID on top of this to get API access?

API I am calling:
    https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?start-date={start-date}&end-date={end-date}&metrics=views&dimensions=video&ids=channel=={channel-id}&filters=video=={video-id}&access_token={access-token-of-channel-owner-or-manager}

If I change access token to the token representing the Primary Channel Owner then it works.  In that case I can also say channel==mine.  Otherwise I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden",
        "message": "Forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Forbidden"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the request that you are doing? Also, what is the complete error message that you got? Can you please include it in in your question.

Comment: Added the call and response per your suggestion, thanks.